# drawing an SDL_Rect not working

Tags: c++, events, sdl, draw, rect

I am trying to build an RTS in C++ using SDL. Now I'm trying to make a rectangle which will select units(resizable selection box). It will be a transarent yellow rectangle. 
When I run the program and try to selectg multiplyunits. Nothing happens(I mean drawing the rect. Selecting is not made yet)

This is the code(in main.cpp):

```
...
Uint32 selection_colour;
SDL_Rect box_rect;
int M1X = 0;
int M1Y = 0;
int M2X = 0;
int M2Y = 0;

int W;
int H;
...
void init()
{
...
selection_colour = SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0.3);
...
}
...
while(running)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
        {

            if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
            {

                M2X = event.motion.x;
                M2Y = event.motion.y;

                W = M2X - M1X;
                H = M2Y - M1Y;

                box_rect.x = M1X;
                box_rect.y = M1Y;
                box_rect.w = W;
                box_rect.h = H;

            }

        }else
        {
            M1X = event.motion.x;
            M1Y = event.motion.y;
        }
    }

    SDL_FillRect(screen, &box_rect, selection_colour);

    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```

any suggestions??

Comment: sorry 
Im so stupid. I draw other things on top of that rect